# nested STL structure

Tags: c++

I am wondering about the performance of nested STL structure related to compile and run time. So if want to implement something a nested structure e.g. that way

```
vector<vector<map<int, vector<> > > >
```

How could the access to each container effect on the whole execution time?

Thanks for any help. Giving some specific links considered this issue are very appreciated as well.

My best.

Comment: I am not sure what sort of performance you are looking at at compile time. Do you mean a long compilation times then? Runtime performance: Again difficult to say without actual use cases (are you worried about insertion/deletion/random access?). Note that `vector` s use contiguous memory. Random access works great.  `map` is a different beast (RB trees possibly). You have to measure though.

Comment: Nested vectors aren't contiguous, though. I.e. if you have a vector with 2 vectors with 3 and 4 maps respectively, those 7 maps are likely not contiguous.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Performance of compiler and resulting executable depends on too many parameters. Do some benchmarking to find out.

Comment: @dirkgently, yes, I meant at first the runtime performance through the access in such nested structure and then I want to know whether there is any effect on the long compilation time or generated code size. What you mean that the vector use contiguous memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How could the access to each container effects on the whole execution time?

It's not much to say, even less to reference - except for the STL. `std::vector` provides `O(1)` access performance to the elements (the [*random access*](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Vector.html)), [`std::map`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html) provides [`O(log(n))`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/SortedAssociativeContainer.html) access performance to the elements.

IOW:

```
vector<vector<map<int, vector<int> > > > x;

int i,j,k,l;    
x[i]   // goes via std::vector, O(1)
 [j]   // goes via std::vector, O(1)
 [k]   // goes via std::map, O(log(n))
 [l];  // goes via std::vector, O(1)
```

Most of the accesses would be inlined/optimized out by the compiler.

To help compiler a bit one can cache in a variable some often accessed containers, for example:

```
typedef map<int, vector<int> > map_type;
typedef vector<vector< map_type > > bigvec_type;
bigvec_type x;

int i,j,k,l;

map_type &m = x[i][j];
for ( /* some loop over k and l */ ) {
   m[k][l];
}
```

In the particular case there are not much performance concerns.

My minor nitpick would be is when code uses several such large structures (e.g. moving data from one `bigvec_type` container to another). Though assymptotically performance wouldn't change, the amount of code compiler need to generate would be quite large since it wouldn't be able put all required indexes and pointers into registers. To avoid that, one generally tries to split logically the structure into several layers (akin to my second code example) and provide methods which work with 1 or 2 level of containers only.

Answer (score 0):

The performance is exactly what you'd expect. Just because they are "nested STL containers" does not impose any hidden performance changes.